# EF Core with Pomelo.EntityFramework.Core 3.1.1 - Slow Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (3.1.1) with my MySql database.

I'm running the following query:

```
var model = await _dbContext.Model.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.MyString == myString);
```

Model Definition:

```
    [Table("model")]
    public class Model
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("my_string", TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string MyString { get; set; }

        [Column("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

The Model table only has 1 record.  However, this query takes a whopping 2+ seconds... this seems a little long for such a small simple query.  Have I mis-configured something somewhere?

Comment: Please post the SQL query that is being generated (and [logged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3)) by EF Core. Generally, the first query executed might take longer, because of opening the connection, setting up the `DbContext` etc. But 2+ seconds is very long.

Answer (score 0):

Pomelo and MySQL [do not run truly async queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049481/how-to-use-pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql-provider-for-ef-core-3-in-async-mode).

We are currently performance tuning against EFCore 3.1 and Pomelo.EFCore 3.1.  One of our more complicated queries runs a full 2 seconds faster running sync (10609-11126ms) vs async (13073ms).

Comment: Actually, Pomelo uses [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/), which (in contrast to Oracle's provider) is truly asynchronous. There can be many reasons for a query performing differently when executing it async/sync. Most of the time when async performs slightly slower, the reason is that many more requests are handled in parallel (so network and database server have a much higher workload). Feel free to ask a question here on SO or to open an issue on our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql), if you want us to take a look at it.